# Files created by 'make' aren't getting executable permissions by default

Tags: permissions, compiling, sudo, make, chmod

I'm trying to build a project, and when I use the command `make`, I get the following errors:

```
/bin/sh: line 4: .deps/ipset_bitmap_ipmac.Tpo: Permission denied
make[2]: *** [ipset_bitmap_ipmac.lo] Error 126
```

This file, .deps/ipset_bitmap_ipmac.Tpo, was created by `make` during the build with the following permissions: -rw-r--r--, notice that there's no x. But then `make` wants to execute the file immediately, which fails.

If I go to the file and add executable permissions manually, then the build continues past that point if I re-run `make`. Except that the `make` command will crash again once it reaches the next file. The only option I have is to keep `chmod`ing every single new file.

My question is, why is `make` creating these new files without +x?

Side notes: I'm on CentOS5, `umask -S` returns: u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx, `sudo` doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a name like `.deps/ipset_bitmap_ipmac.Tpo`, it's pretty likely that the file was not meant to be executable.

What's happening here is that there's a line in the Makefile that looks like

```
$(SOME_VARIABLE) .deps/ipset_bitmap_ipmac.Tpo
```

or more likely

```
$(SOME_VARIABLE) $(ANOTHER_VARIABLE)
```

where the value of `ANOTHER_VARIABLE` is `.deps/ipset_bitmap_ipmac.Tpo`, or some variant on this. Due to a bug in the makefile, or in the program that generated it, or because your computer has an unsupported configuration, the variable `SOME_VARIABLE` (which should have been the name of the program) wasn't defined.

More help may be forthcoming if you tell us what project you're trying to build and exactly where you got it, how you unpacked it, how you configured it, what build command you ran.

Comment: Great observation Gilles. I'm building netfilter-ipset latest (dev is same as release currently), git://git.netfilter.org/ipset.git

I'm using the following commands:
./autogen.sh;
./configure;
make

Comment: I will look into the makefile to see if there's such a bug.

Comment: @RodrigoSalazar I checked it out and it looks ok, but I didn't go through the `configure` (it wants a patched kernel source that I don't have). Could you post the `Makefile` (the one in `lib`), and a full transcript of running `make`?

Comment: I finally got it working, you're right it's a makefile bug.

It turns out that if I run make again it continued when it left off and then crashes on the next file. I just ran make 15 times and it completed successfully. then make install worked without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, i think it could be other permission layer.

I've downloaded [ipset 6.17](http://ipset.netfilter.org/install.html) and `./configure` and `make` ran fine.

Since make is calling /bin/sh, there is no need of execute permission, and you could test this on the following way.

Create a script without the x permission, and call it through your shell

```
nicolas@~> cat script
#!/bin/bash

echo "teste"

nicolas@~> ls -l script
-rw-r--r-- 1 nicolas users 26 Abr  5 07:56 script

nicolas@~> sh script
teste
```

Some questions:

Is selinux enabled(check with `getenforce`)?

What are the permissions inside the extracted ipset sources directory?

What is the ownership of the files inside .deps dir?

Have you executed `config` and `make` with `sudo` or `su -s` ?

Comment: I executed configure and make without sudo or su, my user is the owner of all the files in the directory, I have tried setting every thing in the directory 777, and the directory itself to 777 (but the new created file still gets -rw-r--r--). Getenforce returns "Disabled". Thanks for the help

Comment: Additional, probably not relevant note, the tar file that I extracted from has permissions of -rw-r--r--. (Though I did change the permissions of the new extracted folder to 777)